# Django media files not loading

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-media

I have a `users` app, `profile` is a model created in its `models.py`.The `image` is present in `/media/profile_pics/` but even after giving the full path in `src` it is not loading. I cannot figure out why.Adding the relevant files below.

> `models.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='media/default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')


def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

> `profile.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% extends 'base2.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}


<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>profile</title>
</head>
{% block content %}
<body style="margin-left: 300px">
<div class="content-section">
    <div class="media">
        <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}">
        <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="E:\py-projects\hello-world\media\profile_pics\profile1.png">

    </div>
</div>

</body>
{% endblock %}

</html>
```

> `settings.py`

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
print(MEDIA_ROOT)

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),

]
```

> `urls.py`(the main urls.py, not of app `users`)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from users.views import profile
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('users.urls'), name='index'),
    path('profile/', profile, name='profile'),

]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: You don't appear to have set up anything to serve files from MEDIA_URL.

Comment: how do i set it up

Comment: Well surely you can see that you've done something for STATIC_URL but not for MEDIA_URL. (Although note that both will work for DEBUG only.)

Comment: i did set `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`

Comment: Sigh. Look at your urls. See what you did for static. Then do the same for media.

Comment: oh damn i was seeing it as media all along

Comment: damn i feel stupid

Answer (score 0):

i feel stupid for not seeing this :| had to add this.

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.static import serve


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': 
        settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': 
        settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
]
```

And in your settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```